# How can I list Foreign tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, running \d command will list the tables along with their table type. Currently I'm trying to list out all foreign tables that I've created using foreign data wrapper. What is the query to list out those tables?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the manual `\dE[S+]` should do it.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

To see the query behind this, start psql with the `-e` ("echo queries") option.

Or use the `information_schema.tables` view: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-tables.html

The `table_type` column will contain `FOREIGN TABLE` for those tables.

Comment: actually I want to avoid using \d command. trying to find a query that looks like select table_name from schema.relationship

Comment: @Azuan: the most reliable way is to let psql show you the query using the `-e` option.

Comment: documentation does help me. Thanks :) I use this query: select table_name,table_type from information_schema.tables                   where table_type='FOREIGN TABLE' and table_schema='public';

Comment: I don't understand why this answer and gph's answer don't work (the commands say no relations found) but gargii's answer works and shows my table.

Answer (score 24):

Query for listing foreign tables only:

```
select * from information_schema.foreign_tables
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use this command:

```
\detr
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tc.table_name , ctu.table_name  
FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc  
inner join information_schema.constraint_table_usage ctu on ctu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name  
where constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate your answer rathan than posting a sql statement.